# Adding generic list items to Winforms' listbox c#

Tags: c#, winforms, generics, listbox

Hi Im trying to add the items to a generic list. Then on a button click the generic list items should be transferred to my listbox1. This works however, it keeps adding them every time I click the button.

I tried using an if command, 
sometime like this

```
 if (listBox1.Items.Count == 0)
 {
     // this contained everything I am now adding under initialize component)
 }
```

But this generated the error. index value can not be 0.
So in essence this works as is. But I do not want keep adding the items every time I click.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    list.Add("Januari");
    list.Add("Februari");
    list.Add("March");
    list.Add("April");
    list.Add("May");
    list.Add("June");
    list.Add("July");
    list.Add("August");
    list.Add("September");
    list.Add("Oktober");
    list.Add("November");
    list.Add("December");
}

private IList<string> list = new List<string>();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < list.Count; index++)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(list[index]);
    }

    int mnr = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    string mnm = Convert.ToString(listBox1.Items[mnr - 1]);
    textBox2.Text = mnm;      
}
```

Comment: where is your list declared?

Comment: clear the items in your listBox1 before re-inserting them.

Comment: You've to add strings in `Form1()` constructor.

Comment: @ryadavilli Above the `button1_Click`...

Answer (score 1):

This is just an alternative to @Kami's answer, if you don't use the `IList<string> list` anywhere else, then just add the items directly to the listbox:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // This is only called once.
    InitializeListBox();
}

private void InitializeListBox()
{
    listBox1.Items.Add("Januari");
    listBox1.Items.Add("Februari");
    listBox1.Items.Add("March");
    listBox1.Items.Add("April");
    listBox1.Items.Add("May");
    listBox1.Items.Add("June");
    listBox1.Items.Add("July");
    listBox1.Items.Add("August");
    listBox1.Items.Add("September");
    listBox1.Items.Add("Oktober");
    listBox1.Items.Add("November");
    listBox1.Items.Add("December");
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int mnr = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    string mnm = Convert.ToString(listBox1.Items[mnr - 1]);
    textBox2.Text = mnm;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can do here.

Firstly option is to add a call to `clear()` before you load the list.  This will remove the existing items and reinsert them.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();

        for (int index = 0; index < list.Count; index++)
        {

            listBox1.Items.Add(list[index]);
        }

        int mnr = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        string mnm = Convert.ToString(listBox1.Items[mnr - 1]);
        textBox2.Text = mnm;
    }
```

Or alternatively, and probably the better solution is to move the loading into an init function.  As the data only needs to be loaded once per form, this is the better solution.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Init();
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        list.Add("Januari");
        list.Add("Februari");
        list.Add("March");
        list.Add("April");
        list.Add("May");
        list.Add("June");
        list.Add("July");
        list.Add("August");
        list.Add("September");
        list.Add("Oktober");
        list.Add("November");
        list.Add("December");

        listBox1.Items.Clear();

        for (int index = 0; index < list.Count; index++)
        {

            listBox1.Items.Add(list[index]);
        }
    }

    private IList<string> list = new List<string>();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int mnr = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        string mnm = Convert.ToString(listBox1.Items[mnr - 1]);
        textBox2.Text = mnm;
    }
```